# How to pass an object from .cs to .aspx

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am a asp .net beginner. I want to use some objects created at Site.Master.cs in Site.Master. Is there an easy way to do it?

I know how to do it in MVC(by using view(the object)). But how can i do it in normal ASP .net web application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what exactly you want to do.

If you want to insert some string into tag's title you can insert the following thing in **SiteMaster.master** file:

```
<img src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/") %>images/logo.png">
```

instead of:

```
<img src="images/logo.png">
```

In the first case there will be calculated the path from the root of your application. In the second case there will be relative link. This is because server will CALCULATE the value of **Page.ResolveUrl("~")** function and will WRITE it in **src** tag.

You can do the same thing with any other methods, classes if you defined them properly. But I wouldn't recommend you to implement complicated logic in .aspx files (or .master files). Because you can end up with many difficulties with testing and styling such application.

There are other **server tags**:

1. <% %> - an embedded code block is server code that executes during the page's render phase. The code in the block can execute programming statements and call functions in the current page class. [Description and examples](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178135%28vs.80%29.aspx)
2. <%= %> - most useful for displaying single pieces of information. [Description and examples](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5%28VS.71%29.aspx)
3. <%# %> - data binding expression syntax. [Description and examples](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx.aspx)
4. <%$ %> - ASP.NET Expression. [Description and examples](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx)
5. <%@ %> - Directive Syntax. [Description and examples](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz702w3e%28VS.80%29.aspx)
6. <%-- --%> - Server-Side Comments. [Description and examples](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-US/library/4acf8afk.aspx)
7. <%: %> like <%= %> - But HtmlEncodes the output (new with Asp.Net 4). [Description and examples](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx)

**Another way:** you can use JSON to send some data to the client and then process it with javascript. Take a look at [this project](http://json.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 2):

If the `@Page` directive in your `.aspx` file has `Inherits="XYZ"` where `XYZ` is the class declared in your `.cs` file, you can simply add a `protected` field to your class and assign a value to it. You'll be able to access it in the `.aspx` file just by using its name.

You can also use [`HttpContext.Items` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx) to keep objects during a single request:

```
HttpContext.Current.Items["SavedItem"] = "hello world";
```

And use it in page:

```
<%= ((string)Context.Items["SavedItem"]) %>
```

Comment: i got an error when i was trying what you told me, "cannot apply an indexing to an expression of type "system.web.httpcontext"

Answer (score 0):

Any public or protected property or method in Site.Master.cs will be accessible from Site.Master.

> but how to invoke c# code in aspx ?

There are several ways, including [the `<%= %>` construction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5(VS.71).aspx), and [databinding syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx.aspx).

It would help if you explained what you're trying to achieve.